# How render a form many times

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

im developing the create student requiriment for my application.
I have my Student entity, the entity contains two properties:

1. User (instance of User entity)
2. Course (instance of Course entity)

I build the form, but i wish render the form same times via a click button. On this way the administrator could be add any students without refresh the page.

Its is possible ? How manage the submit on the controller ?

Any ideas ? Thanks

NOTE: Im search a similiar  Phpmyadmin behavior when add a new record.

Comment: Does one form contain the User form and the Course form?

Comment: In the ER model, Student is a table that inherit id of User table and id of course table. With Doctrine, map this. Then, auto-generate form with console. Automatically, the form show two combos (User and Course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is create a new object and form (e.g. StudentCollection) that allows for adding the student form using the `collection` type. This will allow you to manage the dynamically adding/removing student forms a lot better.

More on form collections here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

e.g. Assuming you have a student form called StudentFormType, something like this should work. There's a good example on the link above that you should use if you want to know how to dynamically add/remove student forms as well as handle the submission.

```
// src/PathTo/YourBundle/Form/Type/StudentCollectionFormType.php

// Form object
class StudentCollectionFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('students', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new StudentFormType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PathTo\YourBundle\Model\StudentCollection',
        ));
    }

    // ...
}



// src/PathTo/YourBundle/Model/StudentCollection.php
namespace PathTo\YourBundle\Model;

// ...
class StudentCollection
{
    // ...
    protected $students;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->students = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getStudents()
    {
        return $this->students;
    }

    public function addStudent(Student $student)
    {
        $this->students->add($student);
    }

    public function removeStudent(Student $student)
    {
        $this->students->removeElement($student);
    }
}
```

Then in your controller

```
// src/PathTo/YourBundle/Controller/StudentController.php
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $collection = new StudentCollection();

    // Prepopulate the collection with students
    // ...

    $form = $this->createForm(new StudentCollectionFormType(), $collection);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        foreach ($collection->getStudents() as $student) {
            $em->persist($student);
        }

        $em->flush();

        // redirect back to some edit page
        // ...
    }

    // render some form template
    // ...
}
```

Comment: understand your solution, and i like ! i will try implement it now, thanks.

Comment: One question, how map the students property ?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily use the `StudentCollection` object as an entity. I would just use a `getStudents()` in that object to obtain all the students submitted in the form and the persist each of them to the database separately. I'll update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Ok, but  the form not render the combos. I copy your example.

Comment: What do you mean by combos?

Comment: when the form is render, i havent got controlls, only "submit" and "reset".

Comment: I create a collection with one student, and now works. Thanks.